# Loading a FastText Model from s3 without Saving Locally

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-s3, fasttext

I am looking to use a FastText model in a ML pipeline that I made and saved as a `.bin` file on s3. My hope is to keep this all in a cloud based pipeline, so I don't want local files. I feel like I am really close, but I can't figure out how to make a temporary `.bin` file. I also am not sure if I am saving and reading the FastText model in the most efficient way. The below code works, but it saves the file locally which I want to avoid.

```
import smart_open
file = smart_open.smart_open(s3 location of .bin model)
listed = b''.join([i for i in file])
with open("ml_model.bin", "wb") as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(listed)
model = fasttext.load_model("ml_model.bin")
```

Comment: If `fasttext.load_model()` supports a filelike object instead of a file path, you can use an `io.BytesIO(listed)`...

Comment: Good idea but sadly it didn't work, got a `TypeError: loadModel(): incompatible function arguments.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As partially answered by the above response, a temporary file was needed. But on top of that, the temporary file needed to be passed as a string object, which is sort of strange. Working code below:

```
import tempfile
import fasttext
import smart_open
from pathlib import Path

file = smart_open.smart_open(f's3://{bucket_name}/{key}')
listed = b''.join([i for i in file])
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tdir:
    tfile = Path(tdir).joinpath('tempfile.bin')
    tfile.write_bytes(listed)
    model = fasttext.load_model(str(tfile))
```

Comment: In the end, this is still writing a file on disk. You could use `shutil.copyfileobj()` to be more efficient in that case. `str(tfile)` here is only returning the name of the file...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `fasttext` wrapper for the official Facebook FastText code, you may need to create a local temporary copy - your troubles make it seem like that code relies on opening a local file path.

You could also try the `Gensim` package's separate `FastText` support, which should accept an S3 path via its `load_facebook_model()` function:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model

(Note, though, that Gensim doesn't support all FastText functionality, like the `supervised` mode.)

Comment: Thanks for this, it definitely pointed me in the right direction! The issue is related to needing a Path object. I didn't know about Gensim's direct implementation of the package.